# How to compare two parts of a line multiple times in multiple files with specific extension?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**NOTE BEFORE READING:** The following question is described very precisely and that is the reason for the length of a question. If you want to understand the problem, it's better to read the entire thing. Many thanks for all the answers!

I am working on a bash script (.sh file) which will check certain values in every file of a directory. Bash script will be executed in a pre-commit (pre-commit is not a part of the question).

There is a directory that contains multiple .c files in multiple subdirectories. I want to check a part of two lines which are NOT in every .c file but only in some of them. The structure of a file that contains the useful information is as following:

```
/*
@@ SYMBOL = some_symbol1
@@ A2L_TYPE = PARAMETER
.
.
.
@! DEFAULT = some_value1
@@ END
*/
some_symbol1 = some_value1

/*
@@ SYMBOL = some_symbol2
@@ A2L_TYPE = PARAMETER
.
.
.
@! DEFAULT = some_value2
@@ END
*/
some_symbol2 = some_value2
```

This kind of structure is automatically generated by another script.
I want to check if **some_value1** (in comment) is equal to **some_value1** (in variable).

There are hundreds of these variable in each .c file (not necessarily in each .c file).

The main functionality of a script should be:

- Check **some_value1** in comment and variable and throw an error if they are not the same. Script has to go through EVERY .c file in a directory (bash is in root) and ALL subdirectories to find previously mentioned structure.
- Value of variable can be something as 0.06F, where in comment, there is 0.06 (compare only the numbers)
- Value of variable can also be an array: { 0.0F, 0.45F, 0.3F } where in the comment, there is [ 0.0, 0.45, 0.3 ] (without F and difference in braces)

To summarize:

- I want to build a check script that compares **some_value1** (in comment) and **some_value1** (in variable) and throw an error if they don't match
- Useful information is not in EVERY .c file but only in some of them (don't know which)
- Values after @! DEFAULT is a comment where the value of variable is a number (maybe this is not that important?)
- between A2L_TYPE and DEFAULT, there can be desired number of unimportant stuff. (still a comment)

What I tried so far is for loop through every .c file and a nested for loop to read every line in each .c file. What I wanted to implement was a grep command inside for loop to check each line if there is a @! DEFAULT pattern and save it to the variable.

Latest code that I tried:

```
!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

for d in */**/*.c
do
    while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
    do
        grep -P "@! DEFAULT" $d
    done < $d
done
```

This is currently not working because it gives an error that certain grep targets are directories

If any has any questions, I will try to explain it better.

Comment: does assignment of a value appear precisely once per valid file?

Comment: @jhnc, assignment of each variable appears one time per valid file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# search for files with extension ".c"
# execute awk on any matches, using '= ' as field separator
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec awk -F'=[[:space:]]*' '

    # check if first three lines match template
    ( NR==1 && /^\/\*/ ) ||
    ( NR==2 && /^@@ SYMBOL = / ) ||
    ( NR==3 && /^@@ A2L_TYPE = PARAMETER/ ) { ok++ }

    # template mismatch - skip this file
    ( NR==4 && ok!=3 ) {
        printf "%s : ignored\n", FILENAME
        nextfile
    }

    # store first occurrence of some_value1
    # note line number where second occurrence expected
    /^@! DEFAULT =/ { v[1]=v1=$2; n=NR+3 }

    # test second occurrence
    NR==n {
        v[2]=v2=$2;

        # prune everything except numbers and array delimiters
        for (s in v) gsub(/[^0-9.,]/,"",v[s]);

        # output result
        # match exactly or only number list
        printf "%s @(%d,%d) : ", FILENAME,n-3,n
        if (v1==v2 || v[1]==v[2])
            printf "match (%s)==(%s)\n", v1,v2
        else
            printf "mismatch (%s)!=(%s)\n", v1,v2

        # no need to check rest of this file
        # elide to check multiple values per file
        nextfile
    }
' {} +
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code and variables that are used in it?

Comment: lines beginning "#" are the comments. For info on awk, see: [Wikipedia outline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK); [POSIX definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html); ["The AWK Programming Language" book](https://archive.org/details/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/mode/2up)